# Changing servlet location on Init()

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to change the init parameters so that the servlet is created at a different path? I need to create a servlet at a certain path. Furthermore, would it be possible to artificially pass the path inside the init parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by creating servlet at a different path? And what is your concerned purpose?

Answer (score 1):

As already shown in other answers, the servlet mapping is not controlled by the servlet, therefore you can't change that from within a servlet instance.

However, you can work around this by introducing a level of indirection (something like a "dispatcher" servlet): map your servlet to a wildcard pattern (like `/app/*`) and inside your servlet decide the actual action based on the request url path: `/app/X` will trigger some X action, while `/app/Y` will trigger Y.

Lots of web frameworks will provide the full functionality out of the box: you can have a look at Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet` and its `HandlerMapping` concept, for instance.

Comment: That sounds like it could work! How could I implement that with the newest version of Tomcat (no web.XML file)?

Answer (score 0):

`Servlets` aren't created at a certain path. They are Java objects that the servlet container Java application creates. If you are running Tomcat, for example, your application will run from the `/webapps` directory. The most you can do is change the Tomcat configuration to run it from some other path, but you'll have to do this before actually starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't change anything related to servlet path mapping in init, since servlet container has already read mapping from web.xml.

Longer answer - you may want to look at servlet loader in Tomcat for example, perhaps it's possible to either invoke it's methods through JMX or do something else.

If you just want to have several mappings and choose which one to serve depending on configuration - use  [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)